# json {'type' : 'Polygon'} to GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, geometry

I have a `DataFrame` with a json `{'type' : 'Polygon'}` object.

```py
df.head(2)

    osm_id  osm_address osm_building    osm_building:levels footprint   plus_code   ground_height   building_height roof_height osm_name    osm_office  osm_type    osm_website osm_operator
739615941   739615941.0 10 Rhodes Avenue University Estate Cape Town    house   2   {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[264275.9...   4FRW3C6X+WRG    96.75   6.9 103.65  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
740820432   740820432.0 100 Upper Roodebloem Road University Estate Ca...   house   2   {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[264379.7...   4FRW3F62+R87    85.37   6.9 92.27   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

```py
df.footprint[0]
{'type': 'Polygon',
 'coordinates': [[[264275.99887603114, 6241813.834685098],
   [264278.1042860146, 6241837.7936792765],
   [264273.2223782305, 6241838.438089997],
   [264272.6105920747, 6241830.67597108],
   [264271.28497070284, 6241830.787288936],
   [264270.08650652826, 6241814.253691107],
   [264275.99887603114, 6241813.834685098]]]}
```

I've tried (as per [-> [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359285/csv-containing-geojson-format-geometries-to-dataframe)])

```py
def parse_geom(geom_str):
    try:
        return shape(json.loads(geom_str))
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):  # Handle NaN and empty strings
        return None

df['footprint'] = df['footprint'].apply(parse_geom)
```

but fail. It returns `None` for all the features.
How do I parse the `df.footprint` column with a json `{type' : 'Polygon'}` to a GeoDataFrame `geometry` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the [*geometry*](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/data_structures.html#overview-of-attributes-and-methods) of your GeoDataFrame by using [`shape`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.shape) from [shapely](/questions/tagged/shapely) :

```
from shapely.geometry import shape

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=[shape(d) for d in df.pop("footprint")])
```

Output (*only first row*) :

```
print(gdf)


            osm_id               osm_address  ... osm_operator                  geometry
0 739615941.000000  10 Rhodes Avenue Univ...  ...         None  POLYGON ((264275.999 ...

[1 rows x 14 columns]
```

[image]